pac4j SAML migration from 5.7.7 to 6.0.0 RoleDescriptor Error
After migrating from pac4j 5.7.7 to 6.0.0, our SAML login from ADFS doesn't work anymore because of that error:
org.opensaml.core.xml.io.UnmarshallingException: Saw invalid child element {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}RoleDescriptor on parent {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}EntityDescriptor

Error initializing idp metadata resolver
org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Error initializing idp metadata resolver
    at org.pac4j.saml.metadata.SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver.initializeMetadataResolver(SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver.java:108)
    at org.pac4j.saml.metadata.SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver.internalLoad(SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver.java:78)
    at org.pac4j.core.resource.SpringResourceLoader.load(SpringResourceLoader.java:50)
    at org.pac4j.saml.metadata.SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver.resolve(SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver.java:71)
    at org.pac4j.saml.client.SAML2Client.initIdentityProviderMetadataResolver(SAML2Client.java:221)
    at org.pac4j.saml.client.SAML2Client.internalInit(SAML2Client.java:115)
    at org.pac4j.core.util.InitializableObject.init(InitializableObject.java:61)
    at org.pac4j.core.util.InitializableObject.init(InitializableObject.java:38)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getRedirectionAction(IndirectClient.java:115)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.redirectToIdentityProvider(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:240)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:160)
Caused by: net.shibboleth.shared.component.ComponentInitializationException: Unable to unmarshall metadata element
    at org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.DOMMetadataResolver.initMetadataResolver(DOMMetadataResolver.java:67)
    at org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.AbstractMetadataResolver.doInitialize(AbstractMetadataResolver.java:373)
    at net.shibboleth.shared.component.AbstractInitializableComponent.initialize(AbstractInitializableComponent.java:62)
    at org.pac4j.saml.metadata.SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver.initializeMetadataResolver(SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver.java:103)
Caused by: org.opensaml.core.xml.io.UnmarshallingException: Saw invalid child element {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}RoleDescriptor on parent {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}EntityDescriptor
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectUnmarshaller.processChildElement(AbstractXMLObjectUnmarshaller.java:383)
    at org.opensaml.saml.saml2.metadata.impl.EntityDescriptorUnmarshaller.processChildElement(EntityDescriptorUnmarshaller.java:64)
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectUnmarshaller.unmarshallChildElement(AbstractXMLObjectUnmarshaller.java:348)
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectUnmarshaller.unmarshall(AbstractXMLObjectUnmarshaller.java:139)
    at org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.DOMMetadataResolver.initMetadataResolver(DOMMetadataResolver.java:60)

Does someone has an idea what changes in pac4j 6.0 cause this error ? and how to correct it ?
thanks!
============= UPDATE =============
after digging throw logs and comparing the logs genrated by v5.7.7 and v6.1.0: the differences are after
Pac4jHTTPPostDecoder - TokenController - Decoded SAML message
i've got more logs from SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver and SAML2AuthnResponseValidator in 5.7.7 but none of that in v6.1.0...

pac4j v6 comes with OpenSAML v5 so the parsing may be more strict. Maybe there is something wrong in your SAML IdP metadata, like some extra line before <?xml or something like that.

I've tried pac4j 6.0.1 with the same error, but with pac4j 6.0.2 the error is gone but the authentication is KO with nothing in the log except for Get value: null for key: pac4jUserProfiles
org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic - Loaded profiles (from session: true): []

Can you try with the latest version 6.1.0? Thx

Yes i tried the 6.1.0 too along with 6.0.3 to 6.0.6. the result is always no user profile at the end with Get value: null for key: pac4jUserProfiles org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic - Loaded profiles (from session: true): []... i don't know what has changed, there are too much things changed in 6.0.0 and the doc doesn't help me to migrate my controller (i use the securityLogic perform method to initiate the authentication process)

You need to check your logs (org.pac4j at DEBUG level).

in the logs there is something different between 5.7.7 and 6.0.6: in v6 i got those lines: Set key: pac4jRequestedUrl for value: https://XXX/api/v1/saml/login createSession: false, retrieved session: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@7865cc77  but in v5 i've got some more lines between those 2: Initializing: TfrontSamlClient (nb: 0, last: null) Using service provider entity ID https://YYY Initializing: SAML2Configuration (nb: 0, last: null) Bootstrapped  Retrieving keystore from class path resource Loading keystore with type JKS Loaded keystore 
